# Refresh Vue Component on Navigation

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have two versions of my navbar.

Version 1 has a white text color.
Version 2 has a black text color.

The two versions are required because the background color changes to white on some pages....so i need to use the black one.

Both navbars are their own component.  But they share lots of css.

When I navigate from one page to the next, the text-color of the navbar is not changing.   If I refresh the page, then the expected color appears.

It seems to me that the component is being cached.  Is there anyway to force a component to always re-draw?

Comment: Where is your code? Why would you expect a different component to render on navigation? What have you put in place to try and accomplish this?

Comment: Also, I feel that you could do this with one component by toggling a class attribute. Seems overkill to use two separate components

Answer (score 2):

try adding this `:key="$route.fullPath"` in your `<router-view></router-view>`

like this:

`<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>`

adding a key to your `<router-view>` reloads the page if it has a different url but uses the same component.

Comment: <router-view> don't need to provide the key prop